# How can I exclude an image from Hugo's public directory?

Tags: hugo, public-html, static-site-generation

I'm using Hugo to generate a static site. I'm making use of [Hugo's image functions](https://gohugo.io/functions/images/) to create different sized versions of the same image (160px, 240px, and 480px).

That's all working fine but Hugo also makes the original image available (e.g. IMG_7307.jpeg) in the public directory too. **I don't want to publish the original images**. How can I tell Hugo not to include them?

[image: part of Hugo's public directory structure]

Comment: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/dont-put-unprocessed-resources-in-public/11353/13

Comment: Thanks @Rogelio, it works! If you put that as an answer I'll mark is as the accepted answer

Comment: I think a resource dir (instead of a page bundle) does not have this 'problem'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Hugo's [Build Resources](https://gohugo.io/content-management/build-options/#publishresources) options in your page's front matter. See below for an example:

```
---
title: Your Page's Title
_build:
  publishResources: false
---

Hello, world!
```

Any resources in this page's bundle will not be copied into the `/public` directory unless their `.Permalink` or `.RelPermalink` is used.